# Factory.Folder.fetchInstance method not working with paths

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

In my current project using Filenet P8 Content Platform Engine 5.2.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5.3, Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 and Apache Maven 3.3.1

I obtain the connection object with code like this:

```
Connection connection = Factory.Connection.getConnection(url);
Subject subject = UserContext.createSubject(connection, username, password, null);
UserContext context = UserContext.get();
context.pushSubject(subject);
```

where username is `p8admin` and the object store in this way:

```
Domain domain = Factory.Domain.fetchInstance((com.filenet.api.core.Connection) conn, null, null);                   
objectStore = Factory.ObjectStore.fetchInstance(domain, objectStoreName, null);
```

When using the fetchInstance method to get a folder from its path, with code like this:

```
String folderPath = "/Lotto L02‎/Amministrazione AMM_000072_00001";
PropertyFilter pf = new PropertyFilter();    
pf.addIncludeProperty(new FilterElement(null, null, null, PropertyNames.PERMISSIONS, null));
Folder folder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(objectStore, folderPath, pf);
```

if I use the folderID everything works fine, while using the folderPath it doesn't work, getting:

> com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0051E:
>   E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND: The requested item was not found. Folder /Lotto
>   L02‎/Amministrazione AMM_000072_00001 not found. errorStack={ at
>   com.filenet.engine.retrieve.FolderCache.getFolderId(FolderCache.java:515)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObjectIdForPath(IndependentClassRetriever.java:936)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObjectByPath(IndependentClassRetriever.java:867)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObject(IndependentClassRetriever.java:815)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObject(IndependentClassRetriever.java:749)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObject(IndependentClassRetriever.java:362)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.getObjects(RequestBrokerImpl.java:913)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.getObjects(RequestBrokerImpl.java:816)
>   ...

The folder is located in the Object Store's root and the security is set like this:

[image: Folder security]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

FileNet is providing you an error message that is quite clear and concise:

> The requested item was not found. Folder /Lotto L02‎/Amministrazione AMM_000072_00001 not found.

This could be because you are looking in the wrong domain, objectstore, or you do not have permission to read the folder. Perhaps you are trying to fetch a folder that you have not persisted to the objectstore.

Regardless, I do not see anything wrong with the code that you provide; however with the limited information available I can only assume that **the folder does not exist from the perspective of the connection to FileNet**.

Comment: I can assure that the folder exists and that the user I'm using to perform operations has sufficient permissions. Besides it wouldn't work by Id if the folder didn't exist. One little thing: what do you mean with your last sentence?

Comment: last sentence: I don't know where you are running your java code from so I have no idea how your connection is obtained, what user context is attached to the connection, and if that user's access rights are allowed to see the folder.  Your connection, domain, OS, folder, user, all are variables here.
If this is an event action, then the user context is the GCD admin.
if this is an ICN plugin, then you would establish the connection and user context before continuing.